# Time Based Animated Background

Tags: javascript, html, css, animation

I have some code here that animates a full day (from sun rise to sunset):
([demo](https://codepen.io/But/pen/BOEdNP))

I'm curious to know if it is possible to make this even more dynamic, such that the animation moves with the time of day.

For Example: if it is noon, the sun should be at the highest point in the sky. Conversely, if it is midnight, the moon would be at the highest point in the sky.

I have a suspicion it can be done with a few lines of javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var currentTime = new Date().getHours();
if (document.html) {
    '''psuedo_code'''
    while true
        for hour in day
            move sun and moon according to currentTime
}
</script>
```

HTML & CSS:

```
<html>
<div class="canvas">
    <div class="cloud"></div>
    <div class="cloud a"></div>
    <div class="cloud b"></div>
    <div class="cloud c"></div>
    <div class="land">
        <div class="tree"></div>
        <div class="tree a"></div>
        <div class="tree b"></div>
        <div class="tree c"></div>
        <div class="tree d"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="star"></div>
    <div class="star a"></div>
    <div class="star b"></div>
    <div class="star c"></div>
    <div class="star d"></div>
    <div class="wind"></div>
<!-- <div class="swirly-wind">
  <span></span>
  <span></span>
  <span></span>
</div>
<div class="swirly-wind a"></div>
<div class="swirly-wind b"></div> -->
    <div class="eclipse">
        <div class="sun"></div>
        <div class="sun a"></div>
        <div class="moon"></div>
        <div class="moon a"></div>
    </div>
</div>
</html>
```

```
<style>
/*body {
    position: relative;
}*/
.canvas {
    width: 600px;
    height: 600px;
    border: 1px solid #000;
    margin: 0 auto;
    position: relative;
    animation-delay: 1s;
    background: #70c4c6;
    animation-name: daylight;
    animation-duration: 20s;
    animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    overflow: hidden;
    animation-timing-function: linear;
}
.eclipse {
    width: 600px;
    height: 600px;
    /*border: 1px solid #000;*/
    position: absolute;
    left:60%;
    top:20%;
    animation-name: time;
    animation-duration: 40s;
    animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    z-index: 0;
    animation-timing-function: linear;
}
.sun {
    width:70px;
    height:70px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background-color: #ffa;
    position: absolute;
    top: -35px;
    left: -35px;
}
.sun.a {
    bottom: -35px;
    right: -35px;
    left: auto;
    top:auto;
}
.moon {
    position: absolute;
    top: -35px;
    right: -35px;
    width:70px;
    height:70px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background-color: #fff;
}
.moon.a {
    bottom: -35px;
    left: -35px;
    top:auto;
    right: auto;
}
.cloud {
    width: 50px;
    height: 45px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background-color: #fff;
    position: absolute;
    top:20px;
    left: -20%;
    animation-name: cloud;
    animation-duration: 70s;
    animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    z-index: 1;
}
.cloud::before {
    content:'';
    width: 35px;
    height: 30px;
    background-color: #fff;
    margin-left: -20px;
    margin-top: 10px;
    display: block;
    border-radius: 50%;
}
.cloud::after {
    content:'';
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    background-color: #fff;
    position: absolute;
    right: -10px;
    top: 17px;
    border-radius: 50%;
}
.cloud.a {
    top:150px;
    animation-duration: 55s;
}
.cloud.b {
    top:100px;
    left:-15%;
    animation-duration: 38s;
}
.cloud.c {
    top:250px;
    left:-10%;
    animation-duration: 25s;
}
.land {
    width: 100%;
    height: 320px;
    position: absolute;
    left:-50px;
    bottom: -120px;
    background-color: #83a81c;
    border-radius: 50%;
    z-index: 1;
    animation-name: land;
    animation-duration: 20s;
    animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}
.land::before {
    width: 100%;
    height: 200px;
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    left: 40%;
    top: 20%;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background-color: #96be29;
    transform: rotate(-15deg);
    animation-name: land1;
    animation-duration: 20s;
    animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}
.tree {
    width:10px;
    height:40px;
    background-color: #766257;
    left: 200px;
    position: absolute; 
}
.tree::before {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 125%;
    left: -7px;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 0 20px 43px 20px;
    border-color: transparent transparent #bfde3b transparent;
    z-index: 1;

    animation-name: windy;
    animation-duration: 5s;
    animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}
.tree::after {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    bottom:100%;
    left:-25px;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 0 30px 60px 30px;
    border-color: transparent transparent #93ae29 transparent;  
}
.tree.a {
    transform: scale(0.5);
    left: 250px;
}
.tree.b {
    transform: scale(0.75);
    left: 280px;
}
.tree.c {
    transform: scale(1.5);
    left:450px;
    top: 100px;
}
.tree.d {
    transform: scale(1.25);
    left: 530px;
    top: 80px;
    z-index: 0;
}
.star {
    width: 4px;
    height: 4px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background-color: #fff;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50px;
    left: 100px;
    animation-name: fader;
    animation-duration: 20s;
    animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}
.star::before {
    content: '';
    width:3px;
    height:3px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background-color: #fff;
    position: absolute;
    left:20px;
    top:20px;
    animation-name: blinker;
    animation-duration: 20s;
    animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}
.star::after {
    content: '';
    width:2px;
    height:2px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background-color: #fff;
    position: absolute;
    left:-200px;
    top:50px;
    animation-name: blinker;
    animation-duration: 20s;
    animation-iteration-count: infinite;    
}
.star.a {
    top:30px;
    left:90%;
}
.star.b {
    top:120px;
    left:70%;
}
.star.c {
    top:100px;
    left:65%;
}
.star.d {
    top:200px;
    left:15%;
}
.swirly-wind {
    position: absolute;
    top:30%;
  animation-name: wind;
    animation-duration: 12s;
    animation-iteration-count: infinite;    
    animation-timing-function: linear;
}
.swirly-wind > span {
  width: 150px;
    background-color: #eee;
    height: 2px;
  display: block;
  position: relative;
}
.swirly-wind > span:first-child {
  width: 200px;
}
.swirly-wind > span:nth-child(1)::before {
  display: none;
}
.swirly-wind > span:nth-child(2) {
  margin-top: -10px;
  float: right;
}
.swirly-wind > span:nth-child(3) {
  margin-top: 15px;
  width: 75px;
  float: right;
}
.swirly-wind span::before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: #fff 2px solid;
  bottom: calc(100% - 2px);
  right: -15px;
  -webkit-clip-path: polygon(100% 0, 100% 100%, 50% 100%, 0 0);
  clip-path: polygon(100% 0, 100% 100%, 50% 100%, 0 0);
}
.swirly-wind > span:nth-child(3)::before  {
  top: calc(100% - 2px);
  -webkit-clip-path: polygon(100% 0, 100% 100%, 14% 100%, 35% 0);
clip-path: polygon(100% 0, 100% 100%, 14% 100%, 35% 0);
}

.swirly-wind.a {
  top:20%;
  width: 75px;
    animation-duration: 8s;
}
.swirly-wind.b {
  top:45%;
  width: 120px;
    animation-duration: 15s;
  height :1px;
}
.swirly-wind.b::before {
  border: #fff 1px solid;
  bottom: calc(100% - 1px);
}
.wind {
    width: 150px;
    background-color: #eee;
    height: 2px;
    position: absolute;
    top:30%;
    animation-name: wind;
    animation-duration: 8s;
    animation-iteration-count: infinite;    
    animation-timing-function: linear;
}
.wind::before {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    left: 200px;
    width: 100px;
    height: 1px;
    background-color: #eee;
    top:100px;
}
.wind::after {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    left: 400px;
    width: 180px;
    height: 1px;
    background-color: #eee;
    top:30px;
}
@keyframes time {
    0% { transform: rotate(0deg); }
    100% { transform: rotate(360deg); }
}
@keyframes daylight {
    0% {  background-color: #70c4c6; }
    15% {  background-color: #524b64; }
    40% { background-color: #354a4a; }
    70% { background-color: #354a4a; }
    80% {  background-color: #e2b553; }
    100% {  background-color: #70c4c6;}
}
@keyframes land {
    40% { background-color: #4d6932; }
    70% { background-color: #4d6932;}
}
@keyframes land1 {
    40% { background-color: #5b793e; }
    70% { background-color: #5b793e;}
}
@keyframes cloud {
    0% { transform: translateX(0); }
    100% { transform: translateX(850px); }
}
@keyframes rotate {
    0% { transform: rotate(0); }
    100% { transform: rotate(360deg); }
}
@keyframes fader {
    0% { opacity: 0; }
    15% { opacity: 0; }
    40% { opacity: 1; }
    60% { opacity: 0.4; }
    70% { opacity: 1; }
    80% {  opacity: 0; }
    100% { opacity: 0; }
}
@keyframes blinker {
    0% { opacity: 0; }
    18% { opacity: 0; }
    25% { opacity: 1; }
    40% { opacity: 0; }
    60% { opacity: 1; }
    70% {  opacity: 0; }
    100% { opacity: 0; }    
}
@keyframes blinker-1 {
    0% { opacity: 0; }
    30% { opacity: 0; }
    40% { opacity: 1; }
    60% { opacity: 1; }
    80% {  opacity: 0; }
    100% { opacity: 0; }    
}
@keyframes windy {
    15% {  transform: translateX(5px); transform: rotate(5deg); }
    80% {  transform: translateX(7px); transform: rotate(7deg);}
    80% {  transform: translateX(5px); transform: rotate(5deg);}
}
@keyframes wind {
    0% {  left: -800px; opacity: 0 }
    15% { opacity: 1; }
    70% { left: 800px; opacity: 1;}
    80% {  left: 800px; opacity: 0;}
    100% {  left: -1000px; opacity: 0;}
}


@keyframes snowday {
    0% {
        top: 0;
    }
    100% {
        top: 100%;
    }
}
.snow {
    width: 10px;
    height: 10px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background-color: #fff;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
}
.snow.fall {
    animation-name: snowday ;
    animation-duration: 5s;
}
</style>
```

Comment: If you want it to move in "realtime" it is going to be so slow as to be unnoticeable :) You could easily just update the position even once every 5 min instead of needing a continuous animation

Comment: @FluffyKitten I agree, and if a person isn't going to be at the page very long you might not even update (after the initial render) at all. If a person is only there for a minute or so they wouldn't even know the difference.

Comment: To update, however, I would use a simple function called by a window.setInterval(update_position(), 100).